# position operator $ of mongodb is not working in php

Tags: mongodb, php-5.3

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("4f5596973c9059fc05000000"),
"array_to_be_used": {
"0": "4f548df23c9059f406000024",
"1": "4f548df23c9059f406000032",
"2": "4f548df23c9059f406000004",
"3": "4f548df23c9059f406000035" 
}

}

$id ='4f5596973c9059fc05000000';
$collection->update(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),array('$unset' => array('array_to_be_used.$'=>'4f548df23c9059f406000004'))    );
```

Suppose i want to delete '4f548df23c9059f406000004' without knowing its numeric index, so i am using above mentioned code but not working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Positional operators are for arrays, not objects.

Because your data is an object and not an array (which from the array keys looks like it was a mistake), your "best" option is probably to read the object, determine the key and unset it.

i.e.

```
$id ='4f5596973c9059fc05000000';
$row = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
$i = array_search('4f548df23c9059f406000004', $row['array_to_be_used']);
if ($i !== false) {
    $collection->update(
        array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),
        array('$unset' => array('array_to_be_used.' . $i => true))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$pull` modifier.

[MongoDB documention about $pull](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull)

Comment: i used **$pull** . but it also didnt solve the problem. If i directly use index number instead of `$` i.e. `array('array_to_be_used.2'=>'4f548df23c9059f406000004')` then it will delete the element .